# Is it possible to add to/change the functionality of a method through a partial class?

Tags: c#, partial-classes

I have been working on a nuget-package that helps with sending information to Azure's READ-API.
The package itself is done and works great, however I want to add some more optional functionality.In this specific case, I want to send emails when certain milestones are met.

I have made a new project, added my original nuget-package as a reference and went to work with partial classes. While I did succeed in adding some variables and functions, it seems like I cannot change the functionality of the original *sendfile* method.

I was wondering whether or not it's possible through some other way to either add a function that always executes after the *sendfile* function, or to change the functionality of it through an extension package?

My searches on the internet have lead me to the Decorator pattern, however this requires you to wrap the original class in another class, which is something I would like to avoid, because I want to make multiple extension packages.

Comment: Can you overwrite the function in the second class?

Comment: You can't add/change the functionality using a partial class. You can achieve what you want using normal class, interface, or inheritance

Answer (score 0):

If you inherit from the class you can override sendfile (if it is marked as virtual)

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void SendFile() { }
}

public class MyClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void SendFile()
    {
        base.SendFile();
        SendFileCompleted();
    }

    private void SendFileCompleted()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial classes were created to split definition of a class, a struct, an interface or a method over two or more **source files**, hence the following [restriction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods#restrictions):

> - All partial-type definitions meant to be parts of the same type must be defined in the same assembly and the same module (.exe or .dll file). Partial definitions cannot span multiple modules.

If you have the control over the base nuget (it seems so) you can either use [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/inheritance):

```cs
public class Sender
{
    public virtual void SendFile() 
    {
        // do something 
    }
}

public class ImprovedSender : Sender
{
    public override void SendFile()
    {
        // do something new 
        // optionally  base.SendFile();
    }
}
```

Another useful approaches/patterns in such cases:

- [Template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

```cs
public class Sender
{
    public void SendFile() 
    {
        BeforeSendFile();
        // do something or optionally extract virtual SendFileInternal
        AfterSendFile();
    }
    protected virtual void BeforeSendFile() 
    {
    }
    protected virtual void AfterSendFile() 
    {
    }
}
```

- [Dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection) - abstract the `Sender` or some of it's parts as interfaces and use DI so the consumer can completely replace the dependency with custom one.